# What do I do with all of these papers and notes?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I have over 30 notes, papers, burned papers, pirate journals and books in my "Usable Items" category. Can I get rid of these after I read them? Will I need any of these further into the game for any reason?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can get rid of them. Anything that is still required by a quest should be under "Quest Items" (and will generally be moved after you read it).

Comment: Alternatively as suggested here (http://kotaku.com/tips-for-playing-the-witcher-3-wild-hunt-1705588522), just find an easy to access place and stash them by dropping them on the floor. They'll be safe and sound. Personally I sell all mine to a specific merchant in Crows Perch.

Answer (score 2):

You can do whatever you want with those items. Throw them away if you want or sell them.

If you've already read the important quest books or notes or papers they will be removed from the **Quest Items** slot of the inventory.

But...

Why would you want to throw them away?

- They weigh barely anything
- If you forget about a valuable quest detail you can always check back and read it.

I still believe CD Projekt RED will add storage to the game so I advise to hold on to those books and papers. They don't weigh anything.

Once the developers add storage just store them there.

Comment: Because I have 50 of them and it's clogging up my inventory and it's hard to tell which ones I've read and which one's I haven't.

Comment: You have an orange * if you have not read them yet. And they are separated in divisions in you inventory.

Comment: Problem is, that orange star does NOT show if you read it or not. The star disappears with a simple mouseover. I Just sell the notes when i reach a certain amount, to keep the inventory clear.

Comment: it's up to you. The purpose is there. if you want to do that go ahead. but my answer still stands. I like having them around

Comment: Though I wasn't the first, I just downvoted @Lokuzt (sorry), as this isn't actually an answer to the question. It's your preference (which is valid, but isn't an answer to this question).

Comment: I understand and I've flesshed out more of what I wanted to say. I was carried away by my opinion. I still think people are too picky with the inventory thing.

Comment: I sort of agree, but I also dislike some stuff about the inventory - ordering is particularly bad, and having the default order  (seemingly) be Oils, Papers/Books, Bombs, Potions, Food is bizarre to me. Minimising Papers/Books makes sense to me for that reason alone. Clicks-to-eat-food if you've not got it on your belt is pretty high.

Comment: I still think that one day they will lose an important detail about a quest that they had in a book. Like The Witcher 2 riddles and puzzles. and they won't have the book to read it. Remember me when that day happens xD

Comment: @Lokuzt While I agree with having riddles and puzzles and important information in the notes, that adds another reason for not getting rid of them. Which is why I don't want to get rid of them but I also don't want them cluttering up my inventory. Whatever decision I am going to make I'm going to regret it later haha

Comment: @ChaseC I understand but I still believe I don't deserve a downvote. And in a personal note my inventory is like a hoarders house.... don't care. compulsive book hoarder xD

Comment: I do wish I had some place to display all my awesome books / relic swords / bits o' head. But it just doesn't go with Geralt's character. Unless we go back to Kaer Morhen in some DLC... I get that Geralt would read these books, but keeping a literal library on himself at all times seems out of character. ;)

Comment: Well there's an upvote for your opinion, if that makes you feel better :) I appreciate your opinion on what to do with everything. @Jeeva I'd like to save all of my trophies but I've also been selling all of my relic swords. They are worth so much money and everything in this game is so darn expensive.

Comment: Yeah, same. Disassembling them for gems / dust is good, too (relic swords)!

Comment: In Witcher 2 there wasn't any storage either. They added it later. So they will certainly add it in 3. We just have to wait. I think they are going to do it in a better way and that's why it's taking time. Maybe a display like Assassins Creed games. Your personal den in Kaer Morhen where you can place the swords like the Addan Deith. I currently have that sword now

Comment: Nice! I'm going to regret disassembling them at some point, no doubt. Downvote removed, because of the answer on the top line.

Comment: In regards to downvotes, [Tim has lost his keys again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215379/should-drive-by-downvoting-be-more-effectively-caught/215397#215397).  The point of which, if the downvoter wanted to explain it, he would have.  Asking is a lost cause, and doesn't really do much but drive more downvotes your way.

Comment: @Frank quite the contrary. I want to know because I might not be seeing something wrong with my answer. Some people commented above and I actually put my answer into a better state than before.